# Geolocation.latLng() not working in android

Tags: cordova, meteor

I'm using `mdg:geolocation` package and I'm trying to run it in android device but I'm not getting lat and lang anymore, when I tried this few months back it is working fine

I'm using 1.0.3* version of that package

[image]

chrom is throwing above warning which takes me to this [page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins)

as it is a warning it should work.

I even tried to run the app by giving `--mobile-server=https://myapp.com` still it is not working.

any ideas?

My versions
meteor - 1.1.* ( not the latest one)
geolocation- 1.0.3

**EDIT**

I tried using navigator object like below

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
   console.log('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
  'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
  'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
  'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
  'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
  'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
  'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
  'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
  console.log('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

I didn't get any logs in console no error or success callbacks are called

**EDIT 2**:

This is not working when run my app in android mobile, If I run the same in web, I'm getting lat and lang values.

**EDIT 3**

I build apk with --server pointing to `https://myapp.com` still this is not working.

**EDIT 4**

I have one more project with all latest version, tried all the above steps still not working(even with build apk version)

**EDIT 5**

After trying @Adam suggestion I'm getting following error

`code: 3
message: Timeout expired`

tried different option with `timeout`, `enablehighaccuracy` and `maxage` nothing is working yet.

Comment: Does atmoshere uses an external url? Then you shoul whitelisten it, read this doc: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html

Comment: @Joerg  I have `<access origin="*" />` this setup through `meteor`, I strongly feel the issues is meteor sets it's origin as `meteor.local` instead of `localhost`, so according to new chrome updates, it will either allow `https` or `localhost`, but here it is `meteor.local`

Comment: Do you have a content security policy in your `index.html`?

Comment: I have `App.accessRule('*');` this in my mobile-config file

Answer (score 2):

With the Android emulator, you may have to provide a position first. So, run something like:

```
~/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb emu geo fix <longitude value> <latitude value>
```

Comment: I'm using real device not emulator

Comment: Ah, well to have your error code run, you'll have to set a timeout for it. From what I understand, its default is infinity. Try: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error,{timeout:5000})`. Hope this helps somehow; good luck.

Comment: this definetly helped but I'm getting error code: 3 timeout expired error

Comment: GPS tends to be a little strange on each device as well. Simple things like turning off WiFi, restarting the phone, and clearing the cache helped me in a few cases.

Answer (score 1):

You keep with your problem? I was avalaible to make it work by using

```
var geo_err = Geolocation.error();
if(geo_err != null) alert(geo_err.message);
var pos = Geolocation.latLng();
if(pos == null) return false;
```

You need to place it in a helper because it need to iterate over it waiting for a response, otherwise will give always an error.
I use a button to change the state of a Session varible, which later activates the helper so it can be called more than once.
Hope help, I tested in Android and chrome and works.
The only problem was that I can't make the user to ask for permission, if the gps is not activated it gives me

> Timeout error
>   So... looking forward.